# Salesforce Outbound Messages

Tags: salesforce, messaging, outbound

I used postbin.org to test the workflow outbound message service. I specified the criteria like Account Name not equal to Null.But when I create record of Account Object,I am getting 
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog. error in Delivery  Failure Reason.

I dont know to to check it out.Please let me know.Thanks in advance..

Comment: By the way you can ask your question about salesforce directly at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The Outbound messaging feature requires that your listener send back a well formed soap message indicating that it successfully processed the message as its HTTP response. It seems unlikely that postbin.org is sending that response, and hence OM is reporting that as a delivery failure, and the message will get retried again later.